# How to check php version in MacOS sierra?

Tags: php, homebrew, visual-studio-code, mamp, macos-sierra

I have mac os sierra machine. When I start a php project in vs code, I get the following warning

**language server needs php 7, and the version found is 5.6.27.**

So I used homebrew to upgrade to version 7 and confirmed it from the terminal. I am also running mamp which show version 7.
But in the terminal of vs code the php version is still 5.6.27. So I am bit confused?

[image]

I changed the value of `php.validate.executablepath` in `settings.json` in vs code from `usr/bin/php` to `usr/local/bin/php`, but still vs code terminal showing the older version (viz. 5.6.27)

[image]

Comment: Can you run in each console "which php"

Comment: I'm going to guess that each one is pointing at a PHP version that isn't matching some of the others.

Comment: The version installed by `homebrew` will be in `/usr/local/bin/php` so either use `/usr/local/bin/php -v` or set your PATH to include `/usr/local/bin` at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because VM Code still checking /usr/bin/php directory which is php5

You have to configure the path to the PHP executable in the user settings file.
Follow the following steps to change it

1. Go to **File > Preferences > User Settings > Settings.json**
2. Change the value of php.validate.executablePath according to the installed
   directory of php7.

   > "php.validate.executablePath":
   >   "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.14/bin/php"
3. Relaunch VM Code

[image: Setting.json]

4. If the problem remains same, then add the path to PHP7 to your environment variables, run **where php** and **php --version** to verify. To add path in your macos sierra do the following:

   - Within the Terminal, run **vim ~/.bash_profile**
   - Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

     ```
     export PATH=/user/local/bin:$PATH
     ```
   - Hit ESC, Type :wq, and hit Enter.
   - In Terminal run **source ~/.bash_profile**
   - In Terminal, type in **which php** again and look for the updated string.
   - If everything went successful, it should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.
   - In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short)

Comment: In the /user/local/bin/php has the version 7.0.14 So thats one I would like to target. This is how my settings.json looks like now: 

{
  "php.validate.enable": true,
  "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/bin/php",
  "php.validate.run": "onType"
}

My left windows shows the following " // Points to the php executable.
  "php.validate.executablePath": null,"

When I save and reload VS Code, its still showing version 5.6.27 because which php is /usr/bin/php

Comment: Within the Terminal, run vim ~/.bash_profile

Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

export PATH=/user/local/bin:$PATH
Hit ESC, Type :wq, and hit Enter

In Terminal, run source ~/.bash_profile

In Terminal, type in which php again and look for the updated string. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).

Comment: didn't have a clue about vim, hated it, but got hang of it :) and after som frustrated tries, managed to succeed.
Thanks for all you help :)

Answer (score 1):

To find out what version you're using, upload a php file to your server containing the following code...

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

It will tell you at the top of the page.